# Querying Linq to SQL Data Source with OData

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, odata

I am using DBML (not entity-framework) to access some tables in my Web API.

This works perfectly fine, using the `EnableQuery` attribute I can sort, filter, etc via OData.

```
http://my-web-api.com/Clients?$select=Name,Age&$filter=Age ge 21
```

The problem is, when I try to use the "$apply" clause:

```
http://my-web-api.com/Clients?$apply=groupby((Age),aggregate(ID with countdistinct as total))
```

I get the following error message:

> $apply query options not supported for LINQ to SQL providers

The error is fairly self explanatory, that query operation is not supported when accessing a database via DBML.

But my question is - Can I get around this ? Is there a way I could implement the "$apply" myself ?

Many Thanks

Comment: Just as an FYI: LINQ and Entity Framework are two entirely different pieces of code. EF just uses LINQ in LINQ to Entities to map relational DB Entities to your code. LINQ to SQL just translates LINQ queries to SQL queries